# Documenting class instance as a function

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

When using sphinx `autodoc` extension to create documentation how can I document a class instance (not the class itself) as if it was a function? Class has a `__call__` method defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use sphinx extensions to fix the problem. For me the following was enough:

1. in `conf.py`:

   1. add appropriate path to `sys.path` in `conf.py`
   2. replace `sphinx.ext.autodoc` with new module name in `extensions` list
2. in new module:

   1. import `sphinx.ext.autodoc`
   2. create a subclass of `.autodoc.FunctionDocumenter`
   3. create `setup(app)` function which calls `.autodoc.setup()` and then calls `app.add_autodocumenter(SubclassName)`

Note that this will replace documenter for functions, thus you will need to make it useful for them. It is possible to avoid the issue by defining `objtype` class constant with *unique* string as a value, but this will require some more job then just that. Caring about regular functions is easier.

Code is [here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/blob/83d855d3d73498c47553afeba212415990d95c54/docs/source/powerline_autodoc.py) if anybody is interested.

Comment: Be careful, however, when also using `sphinx.ext.autosummary`: Since Sphinx 1.2.1, it [overwrites custom-set documenters](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/commit/574a796) with the default ones. A solution is to set the documenter in the "env-before-read-docs" event, which is called after the autosummary overwrite. An example can be seen [here](https://github.com/F30/salt/blob/autodoc-fix/doc/_ext/saltautodoc.py).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `autodoc` specifically, but you can try this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self):
        ...

c = MyClass()
"""
this is a function-like object.
"""

c2 = MyClass()
"""
this is another function-like object.
"""
```

Or this:

```
#: this is a function-like object.
c = MyClass()
```

Comment: It produces things like `powerline.segments.vim.repository_status = <RepositoryStatusSegment(Thread-1, initial)>`. Documentation attached is right, but it should produce `(*args, **kwargs)`, not `= <RepositoryStatusSegment(Thread-1, initial)>`.